# Removing characters from date in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Im a complete NOOB in VB so please excuse the newbie question

Im running the following code which produces the current system date, as you can see in image below.

```
Dim cyear As Date
                cyear = Date.Now
                MsgBox(cyear)
```

[image]

**My Question**

I'm looking for a way to remove all the characters in the textbox above so that only the highlighted yellow numbers will remain. Which represents the last 2 digits of the current year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a date format string, e.g.:

```
Dim value = String.Format("{0:yy}", DateTime.Now)
```

or

```
Dim value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy")
```

Have a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb).

Answer (score 0):

Format the date before you output it:

```
Dim cyear As Date
cyear = Date.Now
Dim yearShort as string = cyear.ToString("yy")
MsgBox(yearShort)
```

For more formats, read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's best to simply pass a format to the tostring method.

```
DateTime.Now.toString("yy")
```

If that doesn't work...

```
DateTime.Now.toString("yyyy").Substring(2,2)
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)